# Read fields from a WebView in an Android app

Tags: java, android, jquery-mobile

I have an android app which is native, I'm displaying a web page using JQuery Mobile inside the native app, however it has a form and I want to read the fields from my native app and use them when the user clicks submit.  How can I do this? Is there an interface to read form fields on a WebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [document](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) should get you going.

Comment: The following url references one of my projects that does the WebView (JS) and native (Java) communication. http://goo.gl/QHifG

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an interface to read form fields on a WebView?

Not directly. However, there is a clunky approach that you can use:

Step #1: Define a Java class that will receive data from your form, and add an instance of that class to your JavaScript environment via `addJavascriptInterface()`. Unfortunately, you are limited to primitives (including `String`) for your parameters here.

Step #2: Call `loadUrl("javascript:...")`, where `...` is some JavaScript source code, to read the data out of your form and call the method(s) exposed on your class from step #1.